# Freshness of a YouTube API channel playlist feed?

Tags: rss, youtube-api, feed

I am writing an application to read the updates happening in khan academy youtube playlists, by parsing their feeds, but the feed is not upto date

According to this feed url, the last update was on Aug,2012, how to get the latest feed?

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/khanacademy/playlists?v=2

Please tell me if there is anyway to get a new feed

Reg,

Karthi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The youtube method or organizing videos seems like something Khan academy has abandoned at some point in favor or organizing the lists separately. That is why [newer videos](http://www.youtube.com/user/khanacademy/videos?flow=grid&view=0) don't appear in [previous lists](http://www.youtube.com/user/khanacademy/videos?flow=grid&view=1) you would think they would.  They now have a JSON returning RESTful API. For example to see the playlists visit [this](http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/playlists).  There is a [wiki entry](https://github.com/Khan/khan-api/wiki/Khan-Academy-API) explaining more on how to consume these lists and example client code is available on their [github channel](https://github.com/Khan/khan-api/) for a deeper direct use or code dive to emulate in your code.

Answer (score 1):

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/khanacademy/playlists?v=2 returns a list of the most recent 25 playlists that are in the "khanacademy" channel, and that's what I see being returned. It matches what you see in the web interface at http://www.youtube.com/user/khanacademy/videos?shelf_index=5&sort=dd&tag_id=&view=1

Comment: Oh, I thought it was old feed, Is there anyway to get the old feed (whole feed data) also along with the new ones?

Comment: Huh? That's the "whole feed" of the first 25 playlists in that channel. If you want to get the contents of each playlist, that's a different API call.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, yes, the play list feed has only the recently added videos, How to get all the videos in the playlist using API for example this particular playlist has 133 videos http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAEA5E9ACA1508F92 but the feed has less videos http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLAEA5E9ACA1508F92?v=2 is there any way in youtube api to get all the videos from the playlist based on playlist ID?